# How to select features from feature_def created through deep feature synthesis

Tags: featuretools

I am using deep feature synthesis to create new features. How can I select features from feature_def.

For example, I need to select all the features with string "Age" in it. 
I tried the following code  which gave me an error "argument of type 'IdentityFeature' is not iterable"

```
    feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset= es, target_entity= 'titanic', max_depth= 2)
    features = []
    for s in feature_defs:
      if 'Age' in s:
        features.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.get_name()` method on the feature definition. For example,

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset= es, target_entity= 'titanic', max_depth= 2)
features = []
for s in feature_defs:
  if 'Age' in s.get_name():
    features.append(s)
```